# How can I split a string to x number columns and y number of rows?

Tags: postgresql, split

I have a string looks like 'ab bc 123 cd de ef 232' and I need to split this to look like :

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ab | bc | 123 |
| cd de | ef | 232 |

Numbers have to be in the first column, the last string before the numbers has to be in the second column and all characters before that has to be in the first column.

I am working on PostreSQL and have no idea how to do that

Comment: I suggest handling this outside of Postgres.  Generate a CSV flat file with the correct number of columns, then import it into Postgres.  Side note: What is the logic by which `cd de` appears in the same column, rather than `de ef` appearing together in the third column?

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I'll do it that way. ef is the surname and I'm assuming everyone can have only one surname.

Comment: You assume *everyone can have only one surname*. That is a false assumption. Many Hispanic and Mexican cultures (likely to be others) often have multiple surnames, and often non-hyphenated.

Comment: you are right Ybout that, but in a case like this is there any other assumption can I make to be more accurate? I mean if 90% of the people have one surname and the rest has 2, I think it's better to use this assumption. Since I cannot define every single name and surname to the query and even if I do that there are strings that can be either of two.

Answer (score 2):

[step-by-step demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=039230a9c01e3cccd6a84dcb0c7d1787)

You can use regular expressions to split your strings:

```
regexp_match(mystring,'^(.+)\s(.+)\s(\d+)\s(.+)\s(.+)\s(\d+)$')
```

(see how the RegExp works: [demo: regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rs57Ln/1))

This results in an array of strings you expect. This array can be used to fill your table:

```
WITH textblocks AS (      -- 1
    SELECT
        regexp_match(mystring,'^(.+)\s(.+)\s(\d+)\s(.+)\s(.+)\s(\d+)$') AS r
    FROM mytable1
)
INSERT INTO mytable2 (col1, col2, col3)

SELECT
    r[1], r[2], r[3]
FROM textblocks

UNION                     -- 2

SELECT
    r[4], r[5], r[6]
FROM textblocks
```

1. Execute the RegExp which splits the original string into a text array
2. Create two records from the text array and insert it into your table

Comment: Thanks but does it do the split according to the rule that name / surname / id accepting some people have 2 names? Also do I need to make it a function to use it on a database which has many rows can't be coded manually?

Comment: @Alper if you want to make it work with many rows, you need to know the rules to split the row content from a string. Example: with 'ab bc 123 cd de ef 232', I guess the row is splitted by 'number'?

Comment: This one splits at the numbers and takes the one and only text block before the numbers as second column. All text blocks before are taken for the first column. Did you played around with the dbfiddle und regexFiddle I provided? There you can test it. However, it's just a sketch. You may adjust your RegExp if the rules don't fit completely. But this is the way to solve the problem.

Comment: I played around it a little bit and it looks like it will be the solution, thank you.